# How to implement Magento's Table gateway joins correctly

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, blocks, forms

## Synopsis

When I create or save an instance of my custom model, I would like it to automatically save relationships in a pivot table.

1. How can this be done in Magento? and
2. How can I filter my frontend results with this (in a block)?

### Data

```
$data = [
    'store_id' => [1, 2, 3],
    'field_a'  => 'value',
];

$model = Mage::getModel('custom/model');
$model->setData($data);
$model->save();
```

### Table Structure

```
custom_model_table
id
field_a

custom_model_table_stores
custom_id
store_id
```

*P.S. Magento's model structure is **NOT** an ORM but more a Table Gateway*

Comment: As an aside, ORM and table gateway are not mutually exclusive. That said I disagree with your Table Gateway statement; see http://vinaikopp.com/2014/08/25/orm-patterns-in-magento/ for a good presentation of patterns in Magento's ORM.

Answer (score 1):

There is not necessarily a *consistent* example in the Magento core, and I wish that Magento's ORM handled relational data more thoroughly (I think of CakePHP's ORM and related scaffolding). An example is the Page modeling from the `Mage_Cms` module; ref [`Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Resource/Page.php) which has to store page-to-store relationships:

```
/**
 * Assign page to store views
 *
 * @param Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object
 * @return Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page
 */
protected function _afterSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    $oldStores = $this->lookupStoreIds($object->getId());
    $newStores = (array)$object->getStores();
    if (empty($newStores)) {
        $newStores = (array)$object->getStoreId();
    }
    $table  = $this->getTable('cms/page_store');
    $insert = array_diff($newStores, $oldStores);
    $delete = array_diff($oldStores, $newStores);
    if ($delete) {
        $where = array(
            'page_id = ?'     => (int) $object->getId(),
            'store_id IN (?)' => $delete
        );
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($table, $where);
    }
    if ($insert) {
        $data = array();
        foreach ($insert as $storeId) {
            $data[] = array(
                'page_id'  => (int) $object->getId(),
                'store_id' => (int) $storeId
            );
        }
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insertMultiple($table, $data);
    }
    //Mark layout cache as invalidated
    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->invalidateType('layout');
    return parent::_afterSave($object);
}
```

You can follow this approach yourself.